# 在一篇关于墨尔本疫情的文章里，作家为什么先写“爆发”再写“暴发”？

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

在下面的文章里，我们可以看到“爆发”和“暴发”，这两个近义词。这两个词都形容墨尔本里新冠病毒的新增确诊病例，迅速地上升。

> 据新西兰先驱报报道，据称，澳大利亚墨尔本新冠肺炎隔离酒店内负责观察守卫入境游客和归国人员的警卫，被指控与客人发生性关系，导致维多利亚州**爆发**新的疫情。
> ……
> 维多利亚州州长丹尼尔·安德鲁斯承认，酒店员工中有“少量”违规行为，他说这可能是导致疫情**暴发**的原因。
> <sub>[*尴尬！墨尔本新疫情或因隔离酒店警卫与客人发生性行为所致*](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1671100883045133062&wfr=spider&for=pc)，2020年07月02日</sub>

在[这个网站](http://xh.5156edu.com/page/z9461m5337j19790.html)我们可以知道：（1）“暴发”更贬义；（2）“爆发”的使用范围比较宽；（3）“暴发”多用于具体的事物，比如疫情；（4）“暴发”强调事物发生的突然性和猛烈性。可是我不知道为什么在上面的语境里，文章都有“爆发”和“暴发”。

**问题**：在上面的文章里，作家为什么先写“爆发”，再写“暴发”？

我猜是因为在上面的语境中“爆发”和“暴发”没有区别，可是那样的写法不一致。

Comment: It is probably just a typo.

Comment: This is an IME-influenced problem that the editors didn't check for. I was able to reproduce 爆發 as the top recommendation in the first case (導致維多利亞州爆發新的疫情) and 暴發 as the top recommendation in the second case (他說這可能是導致疫情暴發的原因). These IMEs are a bit quirky and their top-recommendation is based on some kind of usage statistic and NLP stuff that I don't know the inner workings of.

Comment: More specifically, typing 疫情暴發 in one go gives 暴發 as the recommendation, while 爆發 is the top solo recommendation.

Comment: refer to https://www.thepaper.cn/newsDetail_forward_6635469

Answer (score 4):

如其他答案者指出，该文章的作者可能打错字了。

实际上，「暴发」和「爆发」两个写法基本上通用，意思为「突然发作」。不过，跟「疫情」搭配的话，则「暴发」更恰当。

> 暴发：指突然发作，多用于山洪、大水或**疾病**等具体事物

中文网站中能发现被多次引用的这篇解释：http://www.chinaqw.com/hwjy/2020/03-16/249584.shtml

[MDGB](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%9A%B4%E5%8F%91) 也提示，「暴发」与「传染病」尤其搭配： *to break out (of disease etc)*

Google 搜索结果也显示，在新华网文章中，「暴发」与「疫情」一起出现得多一点：

> site:www.xinhuanet.com “疫情暴发” 7000多个结果
>
> site:www.xinhuanet.com “疫情爆发” 1000多个结果

[世界卫生组织 (WHO)](https://www.who.int/topics/disease_outbreaks/zh/) 也采用「暴发」这个写法。

Answer (score 2):

正如 fefe 所说，这应该是打错了字

疫情**爆**发 (疫情**爆炸性地**发生/扩散)

疫情**暴**发 (疫情**猛烈而突然地**发生/扩散)

由于爆，暴两者在文章內容中都是合适的副词，他们的差别对文章內容全无影响，读者们大可将两者视为同义词看待

> 爆炸性地 就是 猛烈而突然地

~

As fefe said, it is probably just a typo.

疫情**爆**发 (epidemic spread **explosively**)

疫情**暴**发 spread (epidemic spread **violently and suddenly**).

Since both 爆 and 暴 are suitable adverbs in this context, the difference doesn't affect the context. Readers can just see 爆发 and 暴发 as synonyms to each other.

> 'Explosively' means 'violently and suddenly'

~

Side note:

I suggest you use 作者 instead of 作家 in your title;

- 作者 mainly refers to the author of a particular piece
- 作家 mainly refers to literary writers in general.

We say 他是一名作家, not 他定一名作者

We say 他是這文章的作者, not 他是這文章的作家

Comment: "由于两者在文章內容中都是合适的副词", as an FYI, both 爆发 and 暴发 are verb, not adverb.

Comment: 爆发 is a verb but [爆 is the adverbial component] in [爆发]; 暴 is the adverb of the verb 发. Do you see I only put **爆** and **暴** in bold?

Comment: 爆发 is a single word.  Anyways,

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, it should be 暴发疫情. 强调突然性

爆发：往往是从量变到质变，有个慢慢累积的过程，最后引发某事件.  打个比喻，我们在放鞭炮时，要先点燃导火线，等其燃尽后炮竹才会爆炸。

暴发: 则是强调突然性，意料之外，声势浩大。E. g. 暴发户.

Answer (score 1):

除了使用輸入法軟件與報紙編輯過程出的問題以外，一般來說，假借詞與引申義是用「本字」來代表，而本義是用在本字上添加義符的「繁化字」來代表。例如

- 「然」，从「火・灬」，肰聲，詞語規範寫法是

  - 當然
  - 燃燒（而不是「然燒」）
- 「原」，从「厂」（厈），从「泉」，「泉」亦聲，詞語規範寫法是

  - 原來
  - 水源
- 「益」，从「水」，从「皿」，詞語規範寫法是

  - 利益
  - 充溢

「暴」字（从「日」）的用法一樣，此字本義是「曝曬」，跟熱量有關的詞語寫成「爆」（火山爆發、爆炸），本字通常用在更抽象的詞語上，「猛烈」之類的詞語可能罕見以「爆」、「曝」字的寫法。

---

一說「疫情爆發」與「疫情暴發」可通，但是我認爲如果讓大家以手寫方式來傳寫語音，**huǒshān bàofā** 大量還是會寫成「火山爆發」，**yìqíng bàofā** 還是會寫成「疫情暴發」。在傳寫語音中，人不會考慮 **yìqíng bàofā** 是否含 *explosive* 之義。